# Unable to kill / terminate programs if another terminal window opened

Tags: python, subprocess, kill, terminate

I’m running a program on raspberry pi which opens few other python programs for a certain amount of time and then closes them. What is happening:
- if I’m running the main program from e.g. Python 3 IDE or Thonny Python or other IDEs, everything works fine, it opens and closes all programs as expected.
- if I’m running the main program from e.g. Python 3 IDE or Thonny Python or other IDEs, but I have some other terminal window opened (not even running anything, just opened and sitting idle), it will open all the programs, but it’s unable to close them down after.
- if I’m running the main program in terminal window, it will open all the programs, but it is unable to close them down after.

code e.g. 
*a = subprocess.Popen(['lxterminal', '-e', ' bb.py'])   # works fine every time.*

To start the programs I also tried different variations of Popen and os.system, they work every time fine.

To kill/terminate I’ve tried: 
os.system, os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM), os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT) etc. kill with -9 PID,  subprocess.Popen and then kill() or terminate()

Why if I have some other terminal window opened, it suddenly fails to close other programs?

I need to run my main programs from terminal and be able to close other programs. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Do these commands work if you enter them manually from another terminal window, rather than having Python execute them?

Comment: I can start other programs but can’t terminate them, similar scenario.

Comment: If your commands aren't even working from a normal terminal, then it likely doesn't have anything to do with Python. You might have better luck posting your question to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), without mentioning Python. Just explain how you're launching your programs and trying to kill them, what commands you're using and the output, and ask them why you can't kill a process.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you.